# jasmine test cases for the anonymous function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I need a jasmine code changes, but I have to complete set of jasmine for the anonymous function. I am new to this. I tried but, I'm not able to achieve fully. Please help me.
Html file

```
<div ng-class="{ 'mainPassdownFont mainPassdownNoteLayout noteEditBackground': isBeingEdited(note), 'mainPassdownFont mainPassdownNoteLayout': isNotBeingEdited(note) }" >
    <textarea ng-attr-id="{{ 'note-' + note.PassdownNoteID }}" ng-show="isBeingEdited(note)" class="mainPassdownFont passdownTextAreaLayout">{{ note.NoteText }}</textarea>
    <div ng-hide="isBeingEdited(note)" class="mainPassdownFont passdownTextAreaLayout">
        <pre class="notePre">{{ note.NoteText }}</pre>
    </div>

    <input class="passdownNoteInlineCheckbox" ng-attr-id="{{ 'checkbox-' + note.PassdownNoteID }}" ng-model="cbModel" ng-change="checkBoxChanged(note)" ng-checked="isClaimed(note)" type="checkbox" name="notesCheckbox" value="notesCheckbox">
    <div ng-show="isClaimed(note)" class="downArrowIcon passdownNoteDownArrowLayout" ></div>
    <div ng-show="isClaimed(note)" class="passdownAnnotationFont claimTextContainerLayout" >
        <p class="claimNameLayout">{{ note.Created.By.Text }}</p>
        <p class="claimDateLayout">{{ note.Created.Date.Local | date : 'MMM d, y h:mm a' }}</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="isClaimed(note)" ng-click="claimNote(note)" class="passdownAnnotationFont claimClickTextContainerLayout" >
        <p class="claimNameLayout">Click to Claim</p>
    </div>
    <div class="passdownAnnotationFont authorTextContainerLayout" >
        <p class="claimNameLayout">{{ note.LastModified.By.Text }}</p>
        <p class="claimDateLayout">{{ note.LastModified.Date.Local | date : 'MMM d, y h:mm a'  }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="actionIconContainerLayout" >
        <div class="deleteIcon inlineActionIconLayout" ng-click="deleteNote(note)"></div>
        <div class="editIcon inlineActionIconLayout" ng-click="editNote(note)"></div>
        <div class="addIcon inlineActionIconLayout" ng-click="addSubNote(note)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="btnforpassdownTextAreaLayout">
            <button ng-attr-id="{{ 'btn-' + note.PassdownNoteID }}" type="button" class="btn btnpassdownTextAreaLayout" ng-show="isBeingEdited(note)" ng-click="completeEdit(note)">Save</button>
            <button ng-attr-id="{{ 'btn-' + note.PassdownNoteID }}" type="button" class="btn btnpassdownTextAreaLayout" ng-show="isBeingEdited(note)" ng-click="cancelEdit(note)">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js changes

```
app.controller('passdownCtrl',
        ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$resource',  '$location', 'PassdownNotesData','$window', 'userService',
        function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $resource, $location, PassdownNotesData, $window, userService) {            $scope.passdownNotesData={ "reviewedDateUtc" : "01-01-2000T15:00", "results": [] };
            $scope.reviewDate = null;
            $scope.indexBeingEdited = -1;
            $scope.inputfocus = false;

            $scope.filterText = "";
            // Go get trips from the server via an http Get Call.  If successful, assign the response to
            // $scope.tripData.  If errors occur, assign them to the tripData for the UI to look for
            // and provide the user some possible action.
            $scope.passdownNotesData = PassdownNotesData.getData();
            if ($scope.passdownNotesData.results.length == 0) {
                PassdownNotesData.updatePassdownNotesData()
                    .then(function(result) {
                        $scope.passdownNotesData = result;
                        $scope.reviewDate = parseBoldIQDate(result.reviewedDateUtc); //error
                    }, function(error) {
                        alert('Error getting Passdown Notes data in controller');
                    });
            } else {
                //$scope.selectedRequestIndex = 0;
                //$scope.selectedRequest = $scope.controllerRequestList.requestList[0];
            }

            parseBoldIQDate = function(dateStr) {
                var newDate = new Date();
                newDate.setUTCMonth(Number(dateStr.substr(0,2)) - 1);
                newDate.setUTCDate(Number(dateStr.substr(3,2)));
                newDate.setUTCFullYear(Number(dateStr.substr(6,4)));
                newDate.setUTCHours(Number(dateStr.substr(11,2)));
                newDate.setUTCMinutes(Number(dateStr.substr(14,2)));
                return newDate;
            };

            $scope.noteState = function (cat, checkOpen) {
                var containerName = cat + 'ContainerDiv';
                var containerElement = document.getElementById(containerName);
                if (containerElement != null) {
                    var isOpen = false;
                    if (containerElement.style.display == "block") {
                        isOpen = true;
                    }
                    return (isOpen == checkOpen);
                }
                return false;
            };
            getMaxNoteId = function() {
                // create a new note structure, add it to the list, persist it, and put it in edit mode
                var maxNoteId = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.passdownNotesData.results.length; i++ ) {
                    if ($scope.passdownNotesData.results[i].PassdownNoteID >= maxNoteId) {
                        maxNoteId = $scope.passdownNotesData.results[i].PassdownNoteID;
                    }
                    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.passdownNotesData.results[i].SubNotes.length; j++ ) {
                        if ($scope.passdownNotesData.results[i].SubNotes[j].PassdownNoteID >= maxNoteId) {
                            maxNoteId = $scope.passdownNotesData.results[i].SubNotes[j].PassdownNoteID;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return maxNoteId;
            };

$scope.addNote = function(cat, event) {
                // create a new note structure, add it to the list (local and global), persist it, and put it in edit mode

                // create new note
                var currentDate = new Date();

                var newNote = new Object();
                newNote.PassdownNoteID = getMaxNoteId() + 1;
                newNote.Category = new Object();
                newNote.Category.Text = cat;
                newNote.NoteText = "Default Note Text";
                newNote.Created = new Object();
               // newNote.Created.ClaimStatus = "false";
                newNote.Created.By = new Object();
                newNote.Created.By.ID = 0;
                newNote.Created.By.Text = "N/A";
                newNote.Created.Date = new Object();
                newNote.Created.Date.Utc = createBoldIQDate(currentDate);
                newNote.Created.Date.Local = currentDate;

                newNote.LastModified = new Object();
                newNote.LastModified.By = new Object();
                newNote.LastModified.By.ID = 17;
                newNote.LastModified.By.Text = userService.getUser();
                newNote.LastModified.Date = new Object();
                newNote.LastModified.Date.Utc = createBoldIQDate(currentDate);
                newNote.LastModified.Date.Local = currentDate;

                newNote.SubNotes = new Array();

                // Add it to local and global lists
                //$scope.passdownNotesData.results[$scope.passdownNotesData.results.length] = newNote;
                var dataCopy = PassdownNotesData.getData();
                dataCopy.results[dataCopy.results.length] = newNote;

                // Persist the updated data to the server
                PassdownNotesData.writeUpdatesToServer(dataCopy);

                // Put the display in Edit mode
                $scope.indexBeingEdited = newNote.Id;
            };

            $scope.getNumUnclaimedForCategory = function(cat) {
                var numUnclaimed = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.passdownNotesData.results.length; i++ ) {
                    if ($scope.passdownNotesData.results[i].Category.Text == cat) {
                        // If the main part of the note was updated, add 1 and call it good.
                        if ($scope.passdownNotesData.results[i].IsActive == "false") {
                            numUnclaimed++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return numUnclaimed;
            };
            $scope.checkBoxChanged = function(note) {
                var elementStr = "checkbox-" + note.PassdownNoteID;
                var checkboxElement = document.getElementById(elementStr);
                var val = checkboxElement.checked;
                if (val == false) {
                    // Here we will unclaim the note
                    var dataCopy = PassdownNotesData.getDatacompleteSubNoteEdit();
                    // Update the real data 'and' our local scope copy, and write the real stuff back to the server
                    for (var i = 0; i < dataCopy.results.length; i++) {
                        if (note.PassdownNoteID == dataCopy.results[i].PassdownNoteID) {
                            console.log("inside here ", note.PassdownNoteID);
                            dataCopy.results[i].IsActive = "false";

                            //Update our local copy
                            $scope.passdownNotesData.results[i].IsActive = "false";
                        }
                    }
                    PassdownNotesData.writeUpdatesToServer(dataCopy); // $scope.passdownNotesData);

                } else {
                    $scope.claimNote(note);
                }
            };

            $scope.editSubNote = function(subNote) {
                 $scope.indexBeingEdited = subNote.PassdownNoteID;
                    var elementStr = "subNote-" + subNote.PassdownNoteID;
                 var textAreaElement = document.getElementById(elementStr);
                 $scope.subNotesText = textAreaElement.value;
            };

            $scope.isClaimed = function(note) {

                if (note.isActive == "true") {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            $scope.claimNote = function(note) {
                var dataCopy = PassdownNotesData.getData();
                // Update the real data 'and' our local scope copy, and write the real stuff back to the server
                for (var i = 0; i < dataCopy.results.length; i++) {
                    if (note.PassdownNoteID == dataCopy.results[i].PassdownNoteID) {
                        dataCopy.results[i].isActive = "true";
                        dataCopy.results[i].Created.By.ID = 17;
                        dataCopy.results[i].Created.By.Text = $scope.loggedInUser;
                        var currentDate = new Date();
                        dataCopy.results[i].Created.Date.Utc = createBoldIQDate(currentDate);
                        dataCopy.results[i].Created.Date.Local = currentDate;
                        $scope.passdownNotesData.results[i].Created.Date.Utc = dataCopy.results[i].Created.Date.Utc;
                        $scope.passdownNotesData.results[i].Created.Date.Local = currentDate;
                    }
                }
                PassdownNotesData.writeUpdatesToServer(dataCopy); // $scope.passdownNotesData);
            };

            createBoldIQDate = function(date) {
                var monthStr = (date.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString();
                if (monthStr.length == 1) {
                    monthStr = "0" + monthStr;
                }
                var dateStr = (date.getUTCDate()).toString();
                if (dateStr.length == 1) {
                    dateStr = "0" + dateStr;
                }
                var yearStr = (date.getUTCFullYear()).toString();
                var hoursStr = (date.getUTCHours()).toString();
                if (hoursStr.length == 1) {
                    hoursStr = "0" + hoursStr;
                }
                var minutesStr = (date.getUTCMinutes()).toString();
                if (minutesStr.length == 1) {
                    minutesStr = "0" + minutesStr;
                }
                var dateStr = monthStr + "-" + dateStr + "-" + yearStr + "T" + hoursStr + ":" + minutesStr;

                return dateStr;
            };           
            $scope.filterTrips = function(note) {
                if (note.Category.Text == 'Trips') { return true; } else { return false; }
            };
            $scope.filterWeather = function(note) {
                if (note.Category.Text  == 'Weather') { return true; } else { return false; }
            };
            $scope.filterMaintenance = function(note) {
                if (note.Category.Text  == 'Maintenance') { return true; } else { return false; }
            };
            $scope.filterGeneral = function(note) {
                if (note.Category.Text  == 'General') { return true; } else { return false; }
            };

            $scope.toggleNotesContainer = function(cat, event) {
                var containerName = cat + 'ContainerDiv';
                var containerElement = document.getElementById(containerName);
                if (containerElement != null) {
                    if (containerElement.style.display == 'none') {
                        containerElement.style.display = 'block';
                        if (cat == "Trips") {
                            var buttonElement = document.getElementById("passdownToggleHideShowButton");
                            buttonElement.innerHTML = "Hide All";
                        }
                    } else {
                        containerElement.style.display = 'none';
                        if (cat == "Trips") {
                            var buttonElement = document.getElementById("passdownToggleHideShowButton");
                            buttonElement.innerHTML = "Show All";
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            $scope.toggleHideShowPassdown = function() {
                // We will use the Trips container as the indicator of whether to "open All" or "Close all"

                // TODO - when we get time, we want to animate the open/close of these containers

                var tripsContainerElement = document.getElementById('TripsContainerDiv');
                if (tripsContainerElement != null) {
                    if (tripsContainerElement.style.display == 'none') {
                        // This means we need to open all the containers, and change the text on the button to
                        // "hide all"
                        var buttonElement = document.getElementById("passdownToggleHideShowButton");
                        buttonElement.innerHTML = "Hide All";

                        var weatherContainerElement = document.getElementById('WeatherContainerDiv');
                        var maintenanceContainerElement = document.getElementById('MaintenanceContainerDiv');
                        var GeneralContainerElement = document.getElementById('GeneralContainerDiv');
                        tripsContainerElement.style.display = 'block';
                        weatherContainerElement.style.display = 'block';
                        maintenanceContainerElement.style.display = 'block';
                        GeneralContainerElement.style.display = 'block';
                    } else {
                        // This means we need to close all the containers, and change the text on the button to
                        // "show all"
                        var buttonElement = document.getElementById("passdownToggleHideShowButton");
                        buttonElement.innerHTML = "Show All";

                        var weatherContainerElement = document.getElementById('WeatherContainerDiv');
                        var maintenanceContainerElement = document.getElementById('MaintenanceContainerDiv');
                        var GeneralContainerElement = document.getElementById('GeneralContainerDiv');
                        tripsContainerElement.style.display = 'none';
                        weatherContainerElement.style.display = 'none';
                        maintenanceContainerElement.style.display = 'none';
                        GeneralContainerElement.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }
            };

            var containerElement = document.getElementById("TripsContainerDiv");
            containerElement.style.display = 'block';
            containerElement = document.getElementById("WeatherContainerDiv");
            containerElement.style.display = 'block';
            containerElement = document.getElementById("MaintenanceContainerDiv");
            containerElement.style.display = 'block';
            containerElement = document.getElementById("GeneralContainerDiv");
            containerElement.style.display = 'block';

            $scope.gotoPassdownScreen = function () {
                //$location.path('#/requests/legDetails');
            };
        }]);
```

Jasmine js file..

```
describe('passdownnotes controller spec',function() {
    var ctrlScope;
    var rootScope;
    var userServiceMock;
    var PassdownNotesDataMock;    
    beforeEach(function() {
        module('app');  // load jiops module
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend, $q) {
        ctrlScope = $rootScope.$new();
        rootScope = $rootScope;
        PassdownNotesDataMock = {
                updatePassdownNotesData: function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.resolve(mockPassdownNotesData);
                return deferred.promise;
            },
            getData: function() {
                return mockPassdownNotesData;
            }
        };

        userServiceMock = {
            getUser: function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.resolve(mockUserData);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };

        $controller('passdownCtrl', {
            $scope: ctrlScope, 
            PassdownNotesData:PassdownNotesDataMock, 
            userService:userServiceMock
        });
    }));

    describe('passdownnotes controller',function() {
       it('should have the correct initial configuration', function() {
            expect(ctrlScope.indexBeingEdited).toEqual(-1);
            expect(ctrlScope.inputfocus).toBe(false);
            expect(ctrlScope.reviewDate).toBe(null);
            expect(ctrlScope.passdownNotesData).toEqual(0);
            expect(ctrlScope.filterText).toBe("");
       });
    }); 


});

var mockPassdownNotesData =
{
           "results":[
              {
                 "Created":{
                    "By":{
                       "ID":3,
                       "Text":"Developer, Jeppesen"
                    },
                    "Date":{
                       "Local":"07-02-2015T14:20:26",
                       "TzAbbrev":" MDT",
                       "Utc":"07-02-2015T20:20:26"
                    }
                 },
                 "IsActive":true,
                 "LastModified":{
                    "By":{
                       "ID":3,
                       "Text":"Developer, Jeppesen"
                    },
                    "Date":{
                       "Local":"07-02-2015T14:29:32",
                       "TzAbbrev":" MDT",
                       "Utc":"07-02-2015T20:29:32"
                    }
                 },
                 "NoteText":"test note3333",
                 "PassdownNoteID":1,
                 "AssignedTo":{
                    "ID":0,
                    "Text":""
                 },
                 "Category":{
                    "ID":692,
                    "Text":"Trips"
                 },
                 "DateAssigned":null,
                 "DueDate":{
                    "Local":"07-19-2015T18:00",
                    "TzAbbrev":" MDT",
                    "Utc":"07-20-2015T00:00"
                 },
                 "ExpirationDate":null,
                 "SubNotes":[
                    {
                       "Created":{
                          "By":{
                             "ID":3,
                             "Text":"Developer, Jeppesen"
                          },
                          "Date":{
                             "Local":"07-02-2015T14:20:27",
                             "TzAbbrev":" MDT",
                             "Utc":"07-02-2015T20:20:27"
                          }
                       },
                       "IsActive":true,
                       "LastModified":{
                          "By":{
                             "ID":3,
                             "Text":"Developer, Jeppesen"
                          },
                          "Date":{
                             "Local":"07-02-2015T14:20:27",
                             "TzAbbrev":" MDT",
                             "Utc":"07-02-2015T20:20:27"
                          }
                       },
                       "NoteText":"sample sub note",
                       "PassdownNoteID":2
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {
                 "Created":{
                    "By":{
                       "ID":3,
                       "Text":"Developer, Jeppesen"
                    },
                    "Date":{
                       "Local":"07-07-2015T11:12:03",
                       "TzAbbrev":" MDT",
                       "Utc":"07-07-2015T17:12:03"
                    }
                 },
                 "IsActive":true,
                 "LastModified":{
                    "By":{
                       "ID":3,
                       "Text":"Developer, Jeppesen"
                    },
                    "Date":{
                       "Local":"07-07-2015T11:12:03",
                       "TzAbbrev":" MDT",
                       "Utc":"07-07-2015T17:12:03"
                    }
                 },
                 "NoteText":"Test Passdown Note",
                 "PassdownNoteID":3,
                 "AssignedTo":{
                    "ID":302,
                    "Text":"Button, Jenson"
                 },
                 "Category":{
                    "ID":695,
                    "Text":"General"
                 },
                 "DateAssigned":{
                    "Local":"07-07-2015T11:12",
                    "TzAbbrev":" MDT",
                    "Utc":"07-07-2015T17:12"
                 },
                 "DueDate":null,
                 "ExpirationDate":null,
                 "SubNotes":[
                    {
                       "Created":{
                          "By":{
                             "ID":3,
                             "Text":"Developer, Jeppesen"
                          },
                          "Date":{
                             "Local":"07-07-2015T11:12:03",
                             "TzAbbrev":" MDT",
                             "Utc":"07-07-2015T17:12:03"
                          }
                       },
                       "IsActive":true,
                       "LastModified":{
                          "By":{
                             "ID":3,
                             "Text":"Developer, Jeppesen"
                          },
                          "Date":{
                             "Local":"07-07-2015T11:12:03",
                             "TzAbbrev":" MDT",
                             "Utc":"07-07-2015T17:12:03"
                          }
                       },
                       "NoteText":"Test of passdown subnote",
                       "PassdownNoteID":4
                    }
                 ]
              }
]
};
```

Comment: Please explain what you achieved, and what you are not able to do. Also, reduce the amount of code and show only the code that is concerned by the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
describe('Controller: passdownCtrl', function() {

    var $rootScope,
        $scope,
        $controller,
        $http,
        $resource,
        PassdownNotesData,
        $window,
        userService,
        ctrl;

    // Mock required modules
    angular.mock.module('PassdownNotesDataModule');

    beforeEach(function(){
        angular.mock.module(function($provide){
            PassdownNotesData = jasmine.createSpyObj('PassdownNotesData', ['getData']);
            // Optionally if you want service return some data
            // PassdownNotesData.getData.and.returnValue({
            //  anyProperty: anyValue
            // });

            $provide.value('PassdownNotesData', PassdownNotesData);
        });
    });

    beforeEach(function(){
        angular.mock.module(function($provide){
            userService = jasmine.createSpyObj('userService', ['getUser']);
            // Optionally if you want service return some data
            // userService.getUser.and.returnValue({
            //  anyProperty: anyValue
            // });

            $provide.value('userService', userService);
        });
    });

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$http_, _$resource_, _PassdownNotesData_, _$window_, _userService_){
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $http = _$http_;
        $resource = _$resource_;
        PassdownNotesData = _PassdownNotesData_;
        $window = _$window_;
        userService = _userService_;

        ctrl = $controller('passdownCtrl as ctrl', {
            $rootScope: $rootScope,
            $scope: $scope,
            $http: $http,
            $resource: $resource,
            PassdownNotesData: PassdownNotesData,
            $window: $window,
            userService: userService
        });
    }));

    describe('on controller initialization', function(){

        it('should set reviewDate', function(){
            expect($scope.reviewDate).toBe(null);
        });

        it('should set indexBeingEdited', function(){
            expect($scope.indexBeingEdited).toBe(-1);
        });

        it('should set inputfocus', function(){
            expect($scope.inputfocus).toBe(false);
        });

        it('should set filterText ', function(){
            expect($scope.filterText).toBe('');
        });
    });

    describe('Function: passdownNotesData', function(){

        it('should get data', function(){
            $scope.passdownNotesData();

            expect(PassdownNotesData.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
        })

    });

    ...

});
```

Put any function and properties to the viewmodel of controller, not in the scope:

```
function SomeController(){
    var vm = this;

    vm.someProperty = ...;
    vm.someFunction = someFunction;

    function someFunction(){
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me how to write these functions please help me.            parseBoldIQDate 
$scope.noteState

getMaxNoteId 
$scope.addNote
getNumUnclaimedForCategory
checkBoxChanged 
$scope.claimNote

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('passdownCtrl', function($scope, PassdownNotesData) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.passdownNotesData = PassdownNotesData.getData();

    if (vm.passdownNotesData.results.length == 0) {
        PassdownNotesData.updatePassdownNotesData()
            .then(function(result) {
                vm.passdownNotesData = result;
                vm.reviewDate = parseBoldIQDate(result.reviewedDateUtc);
            }, function(error) {
                alert('Error getting Passdown Notes data in controller');
            });
    }

    var parseBoldIQDate = function(dateStr) {
        var newDate = new Date();
        newDate.setUTCMonth(Number(dateStr.substr(0, 2)) - 1);
        newDate.setUTCDate(Number(dateStr.substr(3, 2)));
        newDate.setUTCFullYear(Number(dateStr.substr(6, 4)));
        newDate.setUTCHours(Number(dateStr.substr(11, 2)));
        newDate.setUTCMinutes(Number(dateStr.substr(14, 2)));
        return newDate;
    };
});

describe('Controller: passdownCtrl', function(){

    var $scope,
        $controller,
        $q,
        deferred,
        PassdownNotesData,
        ctrl,
        window;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('requiredModule'));

    beforeEach(function(){
        angular.mock.module(function($provide){
            PassdownNotesData = jasmine.createSpyObj('PassdownNotesData', ['getData', 'updatePassdownNotesData']);

            $provide.value('PassdownNotesData', PassdownNotesData);
        });
    });

    beforeEach(function(){
        angular.mock.module(function($provide){
            window = jasmine.createSpyObj('window', ['alert']);

            $provide.value('window', window);
        });
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$q_, _PassdownNotesData_){
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $q = _$q_;
        PassdownNotesData = _PassdownNotesData_;
        deferred = $q.defer();

        ctrl = $controller('passdownCtrl as ctrl', {
            $scope: $scope,
            PassdownNotesData: PassdownNotesData
        });


    }));

    it('should resolve promise', function(){
        var data = {
            results: ['0']
        }

        var result = {
            name: '0',
            reviewedDateUtc: '12'
        };

        PassdownNotesData.getData.and.returnValue(data);
        PassdownNotesData.updatePassdownNotesData.and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

        deferred.resolve(result);

        $scope.$digest();

        expect(ctrl.passdownNotesData).toBe(result);

        // function parseBoldIQDate must be executed with
        // result.reviewedDateUtc value
        expect(ctrl.reviewDate).toEqual('Thu Nov 30 0 02:00:50 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)');
    });

    it('should reject promise', function(){
        var data = {
            results: ['0']
        }

        PassdownNotesData.getData.and.returnValue(data);
        PassdownNotesData.updatePassdownNotesData.and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

        deferred.reject({});

        $scope.$digest();

        expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Error getting Passdown Notes data in controller');
    });


});
```

Comment: Thanks. please help meI ask about the following fuctions in controller $scope.addNote, $scope.claimNote and $scope.noteState $scope.toggleNotesContainer  please help me. Main thing i cannot able to proceed on $scope.addNote. please help me for addnote function